# Serialization of Fragment with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've three fragments: A, B and C.

In the B fragment I've a viewpager with 3 fragments.
I replace my content frame with a Fragment:

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, A).commit();
```

Then I replace the content frame with the B fragment and set the second viewpager fragment.
So I replace the content frame with the C fragment.

Finally, I replace the content frame with the B fragment and the viewpager appears on the first fragment.

How can I serialize and save the B fragment instance state and relative inner viewpager state?

EDIT:

**This is my FragmentViewPager**

public class FragmentViewPager extends Fragment {

```
PagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true); //Will ignore onDestroy Method (Nested Fragments no need this if parent have it)

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);

    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    final PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            tabs.setViewPager(pager);
        }
    });

    return rootView;

}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES = { "TAB1", "TAB2", "TAB3"};

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0: return Frag1.newInstance(position);
            case 1: return Frag2.newInstance(position);
            case 2: return Frag3.newInstance(position);
        }
        return Frag1.newInstance(position);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is much simpler as you might expect:

I assume the `Adapter` for you `ViewPager` looks something like this:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

The problem is `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in this case. What normally is desired behaviour - that the `Fragment` is recycled when out of `View` to save memory - is bad in your case. To fix that and to keep `Fragments` from being recycled just extend from `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

But be careful! Now all `Fragments` in your `Adapter` will be kept in memory the whole time regardless of if they are visible or not! If you have more than a few `Fragments` in your `ViewPager` I strongly discourage you from using `FragmentPagerAdapter`!

I hope I could help you and if you have any further questions please feel free to ask!

Comment: Hi Xaver, thanks for your response. You're right, I've used the FragmentStatePageAdapter, I change with FragmentPagerAdapter but still not works. I suppose that is because the Fragment call always the onCreateView, so the adapter was recreating. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you maybe show more of your code? I can only guess what the problem might be without seeing what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you are instantiating the `Adapter` in `onCreateView()`. Even if the `Fragment` is kept in memory, its view hierarchy is detached from the `Activity`, so it may be destroyed at any time. Instantiate your adapter outside of `onCreateView()`. I am not sure about which lifecycle methods are called by the `FragmentPagerAdapter` but try putting it in `onCreate()` or something similar.

Comment: I just confirmed it, use `onCreate()`! In the [**official documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) is an example implementation, you can compare this with your code if you are having trouble.

Comment: I've moved adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) into onCreate method, but still not works. The ViewPager is always in the first tab.

Comment: Oh, well, yes if the view hierarchy is destroyed the `ViewPager` is destroyed and looses its state. Save the page the `ViewPager` is on and reset it in `onViewCreated()` to fix it.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to save the currentItem index to Bundle and restore it when the fragment lifecycle invokes the onViewCreated method?

Comment: Yes try it, I am not 100% about the lifecycle methods invoked by `FragmentPagerAdapter` so I am not sure it will work, but it's what I would try first!

Comment: Ok, this is a way to store the current viewpager page, but the problem persist: how can I serialize the fragment state into viewpager?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to save? What information is being lost?

Comment: For example, in my viewpager fragment I've some edittext with compiled text.

Comment: Are you overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` somewhere without calling `super.onSaveInstanceState()`?

Comment: Yes, but when I switch the fragment B to fragment C the method was not called.

Comment: Where are you overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` without calling `super.onSaveInstanceState()`? The text in `EditTexts` and `TextViews` is saved automatically, but you can break that mechanism by overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` without calling `super.onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: Or `onRestoreInstanceState()` both super calls have to be in  place for this to work.

Comment: Ok, I've changed some things on father fragment. Before I always re-instantiate the Fragment B object, now I reuse the object and the viewpager is correctly set to previous item. But the inner fragment still lost the changes in the EditText or Spinner that I use (for example). Is there a way to serialize the fragments state into viewpager when the fragment go into onPause?

Comment: First of all: you cannot serialize a `Fragment`, I just reread your question and now I think I understand what you are trying to do. Give me some time to think about a simple solution.

Comment: But the viewpager shouldn't auto-serialize its inner fragments?

Comment: What do you mean with `auto-serialize`? Do you know what serialization is? You constantly talk about wanting to serialize `Fragments` but it doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I think you are not going to get around persisting the data yourself to solve this. Use `SharePreferences` or something similar and save everything important.